# Insert Excel sheet data to an existing Big Query table

Tags: excel, google-bigquery, pybigquery

We have an existing table on bigquery that gets updated via a scheduler that checks ftp server and upload the new added data into it.

The issue is that few days were dropped from the FTP and now I need to upload the data manually into the table.

Hopefully, I didn't want to create another table and upload the data into it and then make union between the two tables, I was looking for a solution that would insert the sheets to the main table right away

Comment: I guess you use python to read in the excel document from the ftp and then let python insert the data in bigquery.  You need to talk to the person who did this route. Otherwise you need to upload manually in onther table and insert this data into the main table.

Comment: If I insert data from table X to table Y , would it be possible to delete table X later?

Comment: If you upload your missing data in table X and after the insert to the main table Y, you can delete the table X.